# collecting two different numbers in a single input text field (php)

Tags: php

how do I collect numbers from a single input differently with post method in php? For example `<input type="text" name="numbers" value="numbers">` entry, the user typed 2021, can we collect 20 and 21 separately and print the result of 41 ?

Comment: I am sorry. But your question is not quite clear. for example what is the min and max size of the numbers? If user types 123 then what should be the output?

Comment: As you receive strings from a form, you can split the input, and do math.

Comment: Tell them to use a separator and then explode said separator. Example: Input: `20,21`. then `$arr = explode("," , $input);`. `$arr[0] + $arr[1]`. If you don't do have them use a separator then how do you know if they didn't mean 202 and 1 (or other variations)?

Comment: I don't want to use a separator. Let's say that a maximum of two numbers are entered in all conditions 21, 14, 56, ....

Comment: <input type="text" name="numbers[]" value="numbers"> it will returns an array

Comment: Improve your Question!
Could you give examples with a description of the codes, for your question?

This practice will considerably improve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your code, but it will work only for 4 digit number, what if user enter 5 digit or 3 digit number?

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="enter a number">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['number'])) {
    $number = $_POST['number'];        
    $number1 = substr($number, 2);
    $number2 = substr($number, 0, 2);
    $add = $number1 + $number2;
    echo $add;
}
?>
```

Comment: if(strlen($number) == 4) with this ok thanks so much